# /$metadata is not a supported on Azure API Management (AAM) for onboarded OData V4 APIs

Tags: openapi, azure-api-management

I have onboarded my OData V4 APIs on to Azure API Management (gateway) through `open API spec 3.0` 
I have defined a set of `OData` endpoints available under the spec and I can access the same easily (with or without OData functionalities like `$top, $skip, $filter, etc`).
However, I'm trying to get `/$metadata` result and I get "`500 internal server error`".
I've even tried by adding "`/$metadata`" as one of the endpoints under `'paths'` of spec (same result).

```
paths:
  /$metadata:
    get:
      summary: getMetadata
      description: getMetadata
      operationId: getMetadata
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Metadata
```

I can add **"/*"** as a path, which would give me a list of entities when I just hit `'https://AAM_Url'<br />`
But I don't want to do that as it would accept any junk request like `/fgfdgdg` and make a call to backend service...

Comment: I've not added 'content' part of response... like
```
content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref:
```
Hope that doesn't cause any issues... coz it got working without it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. It worked on adding "/$metadata" in spec as one of the paths.

There was a bug in my outbound policy which was causing the issue. I was trying to read the response onto a JObject, but /$metadata gives response in XML, hence due to conversion error I was getting 500 internal server error as response.